# uninstall Meteor

Tags: meteor, osx-mountain-lion, uninstallation

I installed Meteor quite some time ago to have a play now I dont use it anymore, how would I go about uninstalling it on Mountain Lion?

I have `meteor -v` in the terminal and I have found a folder in `/usr/local/` called meteor so can confirm that it is still installed on my system.

Comment: This is hardly offtopic.  If one is trying to make sure their Meteor installation is installed correctly, and have to do a reinstall, this is totally relevant information.  Shouldn't have been closed.

Comment: on newer versions make sure you `trash ~/.meteor` since it's quite large... 1.6 gigs on mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right, meteor is located in the `/usr/local/meteor` directory.  To uninstall it, type the following in the terminal:

```
rm -fR /usr/local/meteor
```

Comment: So is that it then? It has no other folder or files located anywhere else?

Comment: You can see what the installer script does by typing `curl https://install.meteor.com | more`

Comment: I just typed that into the terminal and it didnt actually tell me much apart from it wasnt going install

Comment: With version 0.6.0, the installation path has been updated to ~\.meteor, I believe.